# Gaussian type integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-a^2 x^2}}{1 + x^2} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral, error-function

When working a proof, I reached an expression similar to this:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-a^2 x^2}}{1 + x^2} \mathrm{d}x$$

I've tried the following:

**1.** I tried squaring and combining and converting to polar coordinates, like one would solve a standard Gaussian.  However, this yielded something which seems no more amenable to a solution:

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r \mathrm{e}^{-a^2 r^2}}{(1 + r^2 \sin^2(\theta))(1 + r^2 \cos^2(\theta))} \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta$$

**2.** I tried doing a trig substitution, t = tan u, and I have no idea what to do from there.

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \mathrm{e}^{-a^2 \tan^2(u)} \mathrm{d}u$$

**3.** I looked into doing $u^2 = 1 + x^2$ but this gives us a ugly dx that I don't know how to handle, and moreover, I think I'm breaking my limits of integration (because Mathematica no longer solves it.):

$$u^2 = 1 + x^2$$

$$2 u \mathrm{d}u = 2 x \mathrm{d}x$$

$$\mathrm{d}x = \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 - 1}}$$
$$\mathrm{e}^{a^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-a^2 u^2}}{u \sqrt{u^2 - 1}} \mathrm{d}u$$

**4.** I looked into some form of differentiation under the integral, but that didn't seem to yield anything that looked promising.  (I checked parameterizing x^2 to x^b in both places, and in either place, and nothing canceled cleanly.)

I have a solution from Mathematica, it's:

$$\pi  e^{a^2} \text{erfc}(a)$$

But I'd like to know how to arrive at this.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: From where?  I can pull out a factor of pi from part 3, but that just gives me an integral that I can't solve that is supposedly equal to erfc(a), but doesn't look like any form of erfc(a) that I recognize.

Comment: This is a good example where we can use Parseval's theorem together with : $e^{-\pi x^2}, e^{-\pi \xi^2}$ and $\frac{1/\pi}{1+x^2}, e^{-2\pi |\xi|}$ are Fourier transform pairs. Thus it reduces to $\int_0^\infty e^{-2 \pi \xi -\pi \xi^2}d\xi$ which is easily seen to be what mathematica claims.

Comment: hint: try differentation under the integral sign

Comment: Look at $F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-a x^2}}{1+x^2}dx, G(a) = \pi e^{-a}+F(a) =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-a(1+ x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx$ and $(G(a^2))'$

Comment: Also, complex integration with a contour on upper half plane gives us the result as we have $z=i$ in this domain!

Comment: @MyGlasses That won't work ... the contribution from the semi-circular arc does not tend to $0$ as the radius of the circle goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $F$ be the function
$$F(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-a^{2}x^{2}}}{1+x^2}dx$$
We take the derivative w.r.t $a$
$$F^{\prime}(a)=\frac{d}{da}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-a^{2}x^{2}}}{1+x^2}dx\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d}{da}\left(\frac{e^{-a^{2}x^{2}}}{1+x^2}\right)dx
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-2ax^{2}e^{-a^{2}x^{2}}}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-2a\big((x^{2}+1)-1\big)e^{-a^{2}x^{2}}}{1+x^2}dx
=-2a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a^{2}x^{2}}dx+2aF(a)
=-2a\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^2}}+2aF(a)$$
Then 
$$F^{\prime}(a)=2a\left(F(a)-\sqrt{\pi}\,\frac{1}{\vert{a}\vert}\right)
=2aF(a)-2\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{sign}(a).$$
Then you have a differential equation:
$$ F^{\prime}(a)-2a\,F(a)=-2\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{sign}(a) $$
with initial condition $F(0)=\pi$.
This fisrt order ode has integrant factor:
$$\mu(a)=\displaystyle{e^{\displaystyle{\int{-2ada}}}}=e^{-a^2}$$
Then
$$ 
\left(e^{-a^2}F(a)\right)^{\prime}=-2\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{sign}(a) e^{-a^2} $$
this implies
$$ e^{-a^2}F(a)=-2\sqrt{\pi}\int{\mathrm{sign}(a) e^{-a^2}}da+C $$
Finaly
$$F(a)=e^{a^2}\left(C-2\sqrt{\pi}\mathrm{sign}(a)\int{e^{-a^2}da}\right)$$

Comment: Excellent work.  This simplifies down (for a > 0) to $\pi \mathrm{e}^{a^2} (-\mathrm{erf}(a) + C)$, but it's not at all clear to me how to obtain C (which should be 1).

Comment: Just, use that $F(0)=\pi$. :)

Comment: Oh of course *facepalm*  I was substituting back too soon, and I had an extra factor of "a" in the derivation.  How foolish.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 8):

Let $f(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-a^2x^2}}{1+x^2}\,dx$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(a)&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2x^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-s(1+x^2)}\,ds\,dx\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\int_0^\infty e^{-(s+a^2)x^2}\,dx\,ds\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-s} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{s+a^2}}\,ds\\\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}e^{a^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(s+a^2)}}{\sqrt{s+a^2}}\,ds\\\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}e^{a^2}\int_{a^2}^\infty  \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt t}\,dt\\\\
&=2\sqrt{\pi}e^{a^2}\int_{|a|}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du\\\\
&=\pi e^{a^2}\text{erfc}(|a|)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach where we first make use of an auxiliary function.

Before proceeding we recall the definitions for the *error function* $\text{erf}(x)$ and the *complementary error function* $\text{erfc}(x)$:
$$\text{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int^x_0 e^{-t^2} \, dt$$
and
$$\text{erfc}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int^\infty_x e^{-t^2} \, dt,$$
respectively such that
$$\text{erf}(x) = 1 - \text{erfc}(x).$$

The idea here is to consider an auxiliary function, related to our
function of interest $f(a)$, but which turns our to be a constant
function for all $a$ in its domain.

Start by considering the following auxiliary function
\begin{equation}
  I(a) = \left (\int^a_0 e^{-t^2} \, dt \right )^2 + \int^1_0
  \frac{e^{-a^2 (t^2 + 1)}}{1 + t^2} \, dt, \,\, a > 0.
  \tag1
\end{equation}
Note the term appearing between the brackets is nothing more than the error function. On differentiating the auxiliary function with respect to $a$ we obtain
$$I'(a) = 2 e^{-a^2} \int^a_0 e^{-t^2} \, dt - 2a e^{-a^2} \int^1_0
e^{-a^2 t^2} \, dt.$$
In obtaining this result, Leibniz' rule for differentiating under the
integral sign has been used. In the second integral, if a substitution
of $u = at$ is made, the result $I'(a) = 0$ quickly follows showing
the auxiliary function is indeed constant for all $a > 0$. To find the value for this constant, letting $a \to 0^+$ gives
$$I(a) \to \int^1_0 \frac{dt}{1 + t^2} = \frac{\pi}{4},$$
so that $I(a) = \pi/4$ for all $a > 0$.

As the first of the integrals appearing in (1) can be written in terms of the error function we have 
\begin{equation}
  \int^1_0 \frac{e^{-a^2 (t^2 + 1)}}{1 + t^2} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{4}
  \left (1 - \text{erf}^2 (a) \right ).
  \tag2
\end{equation}

A similar thing can be done for the complementary error function. In this case we start by considering the following auxiliary function
\begin{equation}
  J(a) = \left (\int^\infty_a e^{-t^2} \, dt \right )^2 -
  \int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{-a^2 (t^2 + 1)}}{1 + t^2} \, dt, \,\, a > 0.
  \tag3
\end{equation}
Again observe the term appearing between the brackets in nothing more than the complementary error function. On differentiating with respect to $a$ we have
$$J'(a) = -2 e^{-a^2} \int^\infty_a e^{-t^2} \, dt + 2a e^{-a^2}
\int^\infty_1 e^{-a^2 t^2} \, dt.$$
A substitution of $u = at$ in the second integral once again reduces
the derivative of the auxiliary function to zero, showing $J(a)$ is constant. Letting $a \to \infty$ in (3) we see 
$J(a) \to 0$. Thus $J(a) = 0$ for all $a > 0$. Writing the
first of the integrals in (3) in terms of the
complementary error function, one finds
\begin{equation}
  \int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{-a^2 (1 + t^2)}}{1 + t^2} \, dt =
  \frac{\pi}{4} \text{erfc}^2 (a).
  \tag4
\end{equation}

Adding (2) to (4) yields
\begin{align*}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-a^2(1 + t^2)}}{1 + t^2} \, dt &= \frac{\pi}{4} \left [\text{erfc}^2 (a) + 1 - \text{erf}^2 (a) \right ]\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \left [\text{erfc}^2 (a) + 1 - (1 - \text{erfc}(a))^2 \right ]\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} \text{erfc} (a).
\end{align*}
Rearranging gives
$$e^{-a^2} \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-a^2 t^2}}{1 + t^2} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} \text{erfc}(a),$$
or
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-a^2 t^2}}{1 + t^2} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{a^2} \text{erfc}(a).$$

So for $f(a)$ we finally have
$$f(a) = 2 \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-a^2 t^2}}{1 + t^2} \, dt = \pi e^{a^2} \text{erfc}(a), \quad a > 0.$$

Answer (score 4):

Instead, let’s treat  $$
I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a x^2}}{1+x^2} d x, \textrm{ where }a>0,
$$
as a parameterised integral by $a$, we can use Feynman’s trick to establish a differential equation similarly.
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
I^{\prime}(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-x^2 e^{-a x^2}}{1+x^2} d x,
$$
then we have
$$
-I^{\prime}(a)+I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2} d x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \textrm{ and }I(0)=\pi \tag*{(*)} 
$$
which is a first-order linear ordinary differential equation.
Solving $(*)$ yields
$$I(a)=\pi e^a(\operatorname {erfc}(\sqrt a))$$

Now replacing $a$ by $a^2$ gives our integral
$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-a^2 x^2}}{1+x^2} d x =I(a^2)=\pi e^{a^2}(\operatorname{ erfc}(\sqrt {a^2}))= \pi e^{a^2}(\operatorname{ erfc}(|a|))\,} $$

---

Footnote: Details for solving $(*)$
$$
\begin{array}{cc} 
& I^{\prime}(t)-I(t)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} \\
\Leftrightarrow & \frac{d}{d t}\left[e^{-t} I(t)\right]=-e^{-t} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} \\
\Leftrightarrow & {\left[e^{-t} I(t)\right]_a^{\infty}=-\int_a^{\infty} e^{-t} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}} d t} \\
\Leftrightarrow & -e^a I(a)=-2 \sqrt{\pi} \int_a^{\infty} e^{-(\sqrt{t})^2} d(\sqrt{t}) \\
\Leftrightarrow & e^{-a} I(a)=2 \sqrt{\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt a) \\
\Leftrightarrow & I(a)=\pi e^a \operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt a)
\end{array}
$$